# Guava EventBus: Dispatching event to multiple subscribers

Tags: java, guava

Since the Guava's `EventBus` documentation is rather short I ask it here:

Is there a way to dispatch events to multiple subscribers or are events always consumed by the first suitable subscriber?

If the latter is the case, would it better to extend the `EventBus` class in order to add such a feature or to implement the whole event bus logic in the own application?

Answer (score 3):

Events are routed to all registered subscribers as long as they match the event type.

It's in the [Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html) of `EventBus`:

> **Posting Events**
>
> To post an event, simply provide the event object to the post(Object) method. The EventBus instance will determine the type of event and route it to all registered listeners.
>
> Events are routed based on their type — an event will be delivered to any subscriber for any type to which the event is assignable. This includes implemented interfaces, all superclasses, and all interfaces implemented by superclasses.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I read and tested that but my test was not valid: I did not register the second listener ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> If the latter is the case, would it better to extend the EventBus class in order to add such a feature or to implement the whole event bus logic in the own application?

I guess, all you need is to add a `handled` attribute to the event and add a `testAndSet` to all your handlers. Doing it manually is surely error-prone, if you have many of them.

You could create a wrapper for your event, which wouldn't let you access it without calling it. Something like

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WrappedEvent<E extends MyEvent> {
    private final E event;
    private boolean handled;

    Optional<E> getAndMarkHandledUnlessHandled() {
        if (handled) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            handled = true;
            return Optional.of(event);
        }
    }
}
```

or do it in more functional way like `callAndMarkHandledUnlessHandled(Consumer<E> consumer)`. For asynchronous dispatch, you'd use an `AtomicBoolean`.

However, because of erasure, this won't work with `WrappedEvent<A>` and `WrappedEvent<B>` as the `EventBus` has no generic information available. You could subclass the wrapper like `WrappedA extends WrappedEvent<A> {}` and work with it. It's damn ugly.

Meaningfully extending the `EventBus` is hardly possible, if you don't want to sneak into its package. The easiest way would probably be forking the whole package and the adding a break after [this line](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/Dispatcher.java#L116).